# App submission with XCode behind proxy

Tags: xcode, proxy

I get this message when I try to submit an app from behind our company proxy.

> Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics.

When connected directly to the outbound router, the upload works.

Anyone got an idea, why? Is Xcode not using the system proxy settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, after adding the second line to my .bash_profile it worked:

```
#this was already there
export http_proxy="192.168.0.99:8080"
#this line added made it work
export https_proxy="192.168.0.99:8080"
```

Activating the proxy in network settings did notwork, very strange..

Comment: in your home folder. it has a dot at the beginning, so it is hidden. check if it exists with `ls -la ~/.bash_profile` otherwise you can just create it.